# Localization in Asp.net aspx page telerik rad control

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, telerik, radgrid

I have used the following syntax to localize a string found between a tag.

```
    <%=ResourceClass.ResourceName %>
```

I would like to know the syntax that I should be using in telerik tag to localize the Header text using the resource I have.

```
     <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="StudentId" HeaderText="StudentId" Visible="False"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet and let me know if any concern.

```
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="StudentId" HeaderText='<%$ Resources:ResourceClass, ResourceName %>' Visible="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Comment: Would please add how I can automatically switch to a language.